# iOS: Draw line between two animating views

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uiviewanimation, caanimation

I have two UIViews with two different animations using UIView.animateWithDuration. The first animation starts right away, the second starts after a 0.5s delay.

How do I draw and animate a line between them like the below example:

[image: animation]

My first attempt was to draw the line as a CGPath and then animate it using CABasicAnimation. This works if the two views (or shapes in that test) animates at the same time, not when the second animation has a delayed start.

I've then been looking into grabbing the values of the UIView frame positions on a continuous basis. That would enable me to redraw my line on each animation frame but I couldn't find any way of doing that either.

So... How *do* I achieve this?

Comment: nice animation. your code attempts would had been more useful.

Comment: The first test just use a CABasicAnimation. The problem with that is that I would need to animate the two points which makes up the line separately. Once it's on a CAShapeLayer, it can only animate the entire shape which doesn't work. For the second approach (positions on a continuous basis), I've found nothing that does the work.

Comment: Dont describe your code, post it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`CADisplayLink`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/QuartzCore/Reference/CADisplayLink_ClassRef/index.html) is probably what you are looking for.

Add an `update` method to your class and perform the animations there:

```
- (void)update {
    // animate view 1
    CGRect frame = view1.frame;
    frame.origin.y += 1;
    view1.frame = frame;
    // animate view 2
    // draw the line/animate another view
}
```

When you want to start the animation, do:

```
displayLink = [CADisplayLink displayLinkWithTarget:self selector:@selector(update)];
[displayLink addToRunLoop:[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
```

Once the animation is complete remove the `displayLink` from the run loop.